# Short Primitive Vectors in a Lattice in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, integer-lattices, arithmetic-geometry

Given $a,n$ coprime positive integers, let $L = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2, ax=y(n)\}$ be the lattice of all points satisfying $ax=y\pmod{n}$.

I want to find an order-of-magnitude bound on the shortest (minimizing say $\max(|x|,|y|)$) vector in $L$ with $x,y$ coprime. If you restrict to merely finding a nonzero vector an easy pigeonhole argument gives a bound of the form $|x|,|y|\ll\sqrt{n}$. Is this still true if we require additionally that $x,y$ are coprime? In particular note that just because $(x,y)$ is in the lattice doesn't mean $(x/g,y/g)$ is, where $g$ is their greatest common divisor - problems can occur if $g$ has common factors with $n$.

Explicitly can anyone prove the existence of a primitive point $|x|,|y|\ll n^{1/2+\varepsilon}$?

Note that if $a\ll \sqrt{n}$ then the problem is trivial by picking $(x,y)=(1,a)$. I am interested in bounds for generic $a\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: There is something wrong with your formulation.  I don't think the $n$ in the error term is the same as the $n$ in the modulo.  Take $a=1$ for instance.  If $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$ then $x-y$ is an integer multiple of $n$.  If it is non-zero (necessary if they are to be coprime) then it cannot be the case that both $x$ and $y$ are bounded in order by the square root of $n$.

Comment: $(1,1)$ is a solution, no? If $a$ is very small compared to $n$ then I'm happy with the solution $(1,a)$. I agree it is not immediately clear such a bound is true - can you provide an example where all the primitive points are much larger than just the shortest vectors in the lattice?

Comment: Then you are talking about a completely different problem than the one I had in mind.  I thought the issue was to produce lots of primitive points on $L$ in a big box around the origin.  You should make it clear for example that if $a\leq \sqrt{n}$, the problem is trivial.

Comment: All right, this problem is interesting, I will think about it.  I think your bound  $n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}$ can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this answer inorrectly conflates multiplication and divison tables mod n so be warned that the proofs of the claims are wrong.  I will edit when time permits.

For now, let me rephrase the problem in terms of a well known series of investigations in analytic number theory.  I will show why $n^\frac{1}{2}$ cannot work and why I believe $n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}$ can.

**Reduction**:
Since we are asking for coprime $x,y$ satisfying $ax\equiv y\pmod{n}$, we must also demand $(x,n)=(y,n)=1$.  The reason is the following:

By Bezout, $kx+ly=1$.  From the congruence, we get $$alx = 1-kx\pmod{n}$$ so $$(al+k)x\equiv 1\pmod{n} $$ so $x$ necessarily has to be invertible, same with $y$.

So the problem reduces to finding the smallest $N$ such that for every $a<n$ with $(a,n)=1$ we can find a pair $x,y$ coprime to each other and $n$, between $1$ and $N$, such that $$ax\equiv y\pmod{n} $$ or equivalently, such that $$a \equiv x^{-1}y\pmod{n}. $$

**Definition**: The multiplication table of size $N$, denoted $\mathcal{M}(N)$ is the $N\times N$ array with $(i,j)$ entry equal to $ij$.  The mod n multiplication table $\mathcal{M}_n(N)$ is the array with $(i,j)$ entry equal to $ij\mod{n}$.

**Claim**: The optimal $N$ for the problem is the smallest $N$ for which $\mathcal{M}_n(N)$ has at least $\phi(n)$ distinct entries coprime to $n$.

*Proof*: If $a\equiv x^{-1}y$ has a solution for all $a$ coprime to $n$ then there are at least $\phi(n)$ distinct ratios and thus $\phi(n)$ distinct products coprime to $n$.  Vice versa, if there are $\phi(n)$ distinct products coprime to $n$, then $a \equiv yz$ so $az^{-1}\equiv y\pmod{n}$ and if $z^{-1}$ and $y$ share common factors, we can just drop them since these factors will not be factors of $n$.

$\square$

**Claim**: $N$ cannot be as small as $\sqrt{n}$.

*Proof*: Look at the $N\times N$ multiplication table.  Its invertible entries are all smaller than $n$ so we can identify $\mathcal{M}_n(\sqrt{n})=\mathcal{M}(\sqrt{n})$, the integer multiplication table.  The result follows now from the following two facts:

**Proposition**: There exists $C>0$ such that for every $n>2$, $$\phi(n) \geq C \frac{n}{\log\log{n}}.$$  This is a well known estimate for the Euler function.

**Proposition**: The number of distinct entries in $\mathcal{M}(\sqrt{n})$ is smaller than $\frac{n}{\log^c{n}}$ for appropriate $c>0$.  This is a fairly recent result that follows from a sharper estimate of Kevin Ford's.

Combining the two theorems we see that the number of distinct entries, $\frac{n}{\log^c{n}}$, is beaten by the number of elements we demand to be distinct ($C \frac{n}{\log\log{n}}.$).

$\square$

**Conjecture** (bold conjecture!): for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, the number of distinct elements in $\mathcal{M}_n(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ is sufficient to beat the demands for $a$.  From the reductions above we see that the conjecture is actually equivalent to your problem.

I think it is true: if we had $\mathcal{M}(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ rather than the mod n version, we know there are sufficiently many entries, even coprime to $n$.  Now I just need to think about the mod n reduced problem, but maybe you or some other answerer can beat me!  After all, the reduction mod n does not create too many overlaps for $N$ still near $\sqrt{n}$, we just need exact control.

I need to write and prepare a midterm now, so I may take some time to update.

Comment: Do you mean to look at the "division table" where we take all ratios $i/j$ of things in the range? Not every $x < N$ will have multiplicative inverse $< N$ as well.

Comment: @XiaoyuHe yes I agree we need to work with the mod n division table rather than the multiplication table so my proofs of the two claims are not correct.  I suspect if we work directly with the division table mod n we can get the claim, but I do not have time to think about this now.  I will not delete the answer yet in case you want to think about something in there.

Comment: Yes, please keep the answer. It is helpful to think about the problem explicitly as the set of ratios of two intervals $[1,N]$, $[1,N]$, which reminds me of a calculation based on [Kloosterman sums](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/kloos.pdf). I will work out the relevant details and see if that proof extends naturally to representations by $x^{-1} y$ to non-prime moduli.